# Using ArrayLists in Superclass/Subclass Framework

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have a question about the use of data structures such as ArrayLists in a simple inheritance structure.  I'm having a difficult time wording it: hopefully you can understand what I am trying to ask.

I have a Superclass `Parrot` and a Subclass `PirateParrot` extending `Parrot`.  In `Parrot`, I have the following method:

```
 public String speak() {
     int rand = (int)(Math.random() * sounds.size());
     return sounds.get(rand);
    }
```

Which returns a random string in an ArrayList called `sounds` which is created in the `Parrot` class.

If I create a separate instance of `PirateParrot` called `polly`, which also has its own ArrayList, and try to call `polly.speak();` without any implicit implementation for the speak method in the `PirateParrot` class, I get thrown an *"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"*

If I specifically copy/paste in the speak() method from `Parrot` into `PirateParrot`, the code compiles fine and runs properly.  What exactly was the problem previously?  Is there a way to make this run correctly without having to copy/paste the speak() method into `PirateParrot`?  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, it's almost certainly better to use `Random.nextInt(sounds.size())`, which would also have the side effect of throwing an exception when `sounds` is empty -- which appears to be what's happening.

Comment: Okay, yeah I wasn't sure about the proper syntax for Math.Random- thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, then the simplest fix would be to not declare another `sounds` variable in `PirateParrot`.  Instead, make sure `sounds` is declared `protected` in `Parrot`, and then in the `PirateParrot` constructor just populate the inherited `sounds` variable with whatever sounds you want the `PirateParrot` to have.

Another alternative might be to have a `getSounds()` method that returns the list and call `getSounds()` from inside of `speak()` instead of referencing `sounds` directly.  Then `PirateParrot` would just need to override `getSounds()` to return its version of `sounds`.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I have never utilized the protected keyword.  Thank you!

Comment: `protected` is an important keyword to understand if you're going to be doing things with inheritance.  Here's a decent overview:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Parrot {
  private final ArrayList<String> sounds;

  private static ArrayList<String> REGULAR_PARROT_SOUNDS = new ArrayList<String>();
  static {
    REGULAR_PARROT_SOUNDS.add(...);
    ...
  }

  protected Parrot(ArrayList<String> sounds) {
    this.sounds = sounds;
  }

  public Parrot() {
    this(REGULAR_PARROT_SOUNDS);
  }
}

public class PirateParrot {
  private static ArrayList<String> PIRATE_PARROT_SOUNDS = ...;

  public PirateParrot() {
    super(PIRATE_PARROT_SOUNDS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing and populating the `sounds` before calling it, do the following:
initialize and populate `sounds` in the `constructor` of `PirateParrot` and then call *superclass*' `speak` method.

Comment: I would say `sounds` is initialized (otherwise a NPE would have been thrown) - but it is simply empty

Comment: by initializing i meant make it not empty ;-) (by filling it)